# Asking for help on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion

I have the shortest answer in my language on a particular challenge at PPCG@StackExchange. I am struggling with a particular part of a program and I want some help. Is it appropriate/allowed/okay to ask for help at StackOverflow if I mention in the beginning that the problem is from a specific challenge at PPCG and give credit if someone answers my question?

Comment: IMO, yes, but keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not really for golfing help - [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) would probably be a better idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get help from whomever is willing to help you. It's customary to mention all people that helped you in your answer, but that's really between you and them, not you and us. SO answers are licensed, so attribution is mandatory in this case.

Other PPCG users will sometimes leave golfing suggestions in the comment section. Here, the recommended procedure is to mention the helping user in the answer, so the comment can be deleted afterwards.

Since you asked about Stack Overflow in particular, I'd like to mention that your question may be off topic for SO. Questions about the scope of SO are best asked on [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

However, you can ask for golfing help in our site's main chat room ([The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)) or—if the problem is sufficiently interesting—ask a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question on PPCG itself. Personally, I'd try the chat room first.

Comment: Although it should go without saying, it might be worth adding a note to search Meta SO first in case this has been asked and answered before.